# Python regEx for datetime mining

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to mine a text into a list using `re`.

Here is what I've written:

```
dateStr =  "20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 20 Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009"
regex = r'(?:\d{1,2}[/-]*)?(?:Mar)?[a-z\s,.]*(?:\d{1,2}[/-]*)+(?:\d{2,4})+'
result = re.findall(regex, dateStr)
```

Even if I stated `(?:\d{1,2}[/-]*)` at the beginning of the expression, I'm missing the days digits.  Here is what I get
:

```
['Mar 2009', 'March 2009', 'Mar. 2009', 'March, 2009']
```

Could you help?
Thanks

Edit:

 This question was solved through the comments.

Original assignment string:
`dateStr = "04-20-2009; 04/20/09; 4/20/09; 4/3/09; Mar 20, 2009; March 20, 2009; Mar. 20, 2009; Mar 20 2009; 20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 2 Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009; Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd, 2009; Feb 2009; Sep 2009; Oct 2010; 6/2008; 12/2009; 2009; 2010"`

Comment: You missed the whitespace, `r'(?:\d{1,2}[\s/-]*)?(?:Mar)?[a-z\s,.]*(?:\d{1,2}[\s/-]*)+(?:\d{2,4})+'`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EsYouH/1). From the looks of it, you want to match many more date formats, what are your pattern requirements?

Comment: That's it! @WiktorStribiżew . I'm trying to match the pattern below for a Coursera Assignment and your answer greatly solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the many approaches:

```
import re
dateStr =  "20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 20 Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009"
regex = r'[0-9]{1,2}\s[a-zA-Z]+[.,]*\s[0-9]{4}'
result = re.findall(regex, dateStr)
print (result)
```

Output:

```
['20 Mar 2009', '20 March 2009', '20 Mar. 2009', '20 March, 2009']
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```py
dateStr =  "20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 20 Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009"
dt = re.findall(r'\d{1,2} \w+[,.]? \d{4}', dateStr)
print(dt)  # ['20 Mar 2009', '20 March 2009', '20 Mar. 2009', '20 March, 2009']
```

The one size fits all regex pattern used above says to match:

```regex
\d{1,2}  a one or two digit day
[ ]      space
\w+      month name or abbreviation
[,.]?    possibly followed by comma or period
[ ]      space
\d{4}    four digit year
```